# Random Access Bundle (RAM) format is not supported by this tool 'React-native'

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing error while Enable the RAM format in my react native project. During the build process it's return

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

Here is changes that i have done in 'app/build.gradle'

```js
project.ext.react = [ 
    enableHermes: true,  
    bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--indexed-ram-bundle"]
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: bundleCommand          : "ram-bundle",extraPackagerArgs      : ["--indexed-ram-bundle"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the react-native official doc, they mentioned clearly,  do not use RAM bundle If you are using Hermes JS Engine [See the Description RAM Bundle for React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires)

Assuming you are utilizing Hermes JS Engine, you shouldn't have the RAM groups highlighted empowered. In Hermes, while stacking the bytecode, mmap guarantees that the whole document isn't stacked. Utilizing Hermes with RAM packs could prompt issues since those components are not viable with one another.

Comment: The solutions work thank you!